# Partition of system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. I did it well. Both are running.

I have a 1TB storage out of which I added 300GB(approx.) to Home of Ubuntu and 10GB to ubuntu-H81M-S part of the OS. I don't know what that is. Now, after using it for one day, I am getting notifications that only 500MB is there out of 10GB and check it.

As I have another free storage disk of 300GB in Windows I want to allocate it to Home and ubuntu-H81M-S. I tried doing it with GParted but I don't know the exact procedure is, so I thought to ask here instead of messing up OS.

I want to know why exactly that much is consumed in one day in that file system and what sort of files it stores. Also being a beginner I need detailed steps to add the storage to ubuntu-H81M-S and Home.

Output of `lsblk`:

[image: Output of lsblk]

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of “lsblk” typed into a terminal without the quotes. This should list your partitions and mount points.

Comment: okay, how can I do that? I am completely new here. Do I have to ask the question once again?

Comment: Please don’t ask the question again. Near the bottom of your question there is a row of links in a small font. One of those should be edit

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to give up some space from your home partition and give it to your root partition. It's up to you to choose how much you move, just be aware that new applications will usually take up space on the root partition and new data will take space on the home partitions. A 50GB root would not be a bad choice.

You will need:

1. Your Ubuntu install media
2. To take a backup of any data you cannot afford to lose.

Step by step (assuming you want to move about 40GB from home to root):

1. Boot the install media and choose Try Ubuntu to get into a live session
2. Run the Gparted app.
3. You should see listed the 7 partitions on your disk
4. Right click the entry for sda7 and select Resize/Move. A small window will open. Enter 40000 in the free space preceding box. Click Resize/Move. On the main GParted panel click the green tick mark to apply the change. This may take a while.
5. You need to move the swap partition (sda6) all the way to the right so there is no space between it and sda7. Right click the entry for sda6 and select Resize/Move. A small window will open. Enter 0 in the free space following box. Click Resize/Move. On the main GParted panel click the green tick mark to apply the change. This may take a while.
6. You should now have space to enlarge your root partition (sda5). Right click the entry for sda5 and select Resize/Move. A small window will open. Drag the arrow head on the right all the way to the right. You should have zero space preceding and following.Click Resize/Move. On the main GParted panel click the green tick mark to apply the change. This may take a while.

This assumes your partitions appear in order sda5, sda6, and sda7 without any others in between. If not use the principles in the steps above to achieve the goal. Once finished remove the install media and reboot

Hope this helps.